# Bar code does not appears on print preview but appears on HTML page

Tags: html, css, barcode-printing

I'v created a prestashop module in which it obtains airway bill numbers from an external API, This number I then add on a webpage and let users to print.

This bar code only appears on HTML page but does not visible on print preview dialog box

I use Smarty for html part since its by default uses by Prestashop.

Hear is my code,

```
<p style="font-family:IDAutomationHC39M;text-align: left">*{$order.other_data.awb}*</p>
```

any idea why this is happening? is there any solution for this?

UPDATE

```
{literal}
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse;font-family:arial;}
td {padding: 8px;}
body { margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #FAFAFA;font: 12pt "Tahoma"; }
* {box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
.page { width: 21cm;min-height: 29.7cm;padding: 1cm;margin: 0.5cm auto;border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid; border-radius: 5px;
background: white; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
.subpage { padding: 0cm;border: 0px black solid;height: 256mm; }

@page { size: A4; margin: 0; }
@media print {.page {margin: 0;border: initial;border-radius: initial;width: initial;min-height: initial;box-shadow: initial;
background: initial;page-break-after: always;}}
</style>
{/literal}



{foreach from=$orders_array item=order}        

    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">

        <table border="3" style="border-style: solid;width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <table border="0" style="border-style: solid;width:100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="{$order.other_data.logo}" alt="logo" height="100" width="300"></td>
                            <td>
                                <h3><u>{$order.other_data.service}</u></h3><br>
                                {$order.other_data.ppaddress}
                                <br>www.postaplus.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table border="1" style="border-style: solid;width:100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="width:40%"><b>From</b></td>
                        <td>
                        <b>{$order.other_data.shipper_name}</b>
                        <br>
                        {$order.other_data.shipper_address},<br>
                        {$order.other_data.shipper_country_code},<br>
                        Phone: {$order.other_data.shipper_phone},
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><b>To</b></td>
                        <td>
                        <b>                            
                        </b><br>                            
                        {$order.params.SHIPINFO.Consignee.ToName},<br>                            
                        {$order.params.SHIPINFO.Consignee.ToAddress},                            
                        <br>
                        <b>Phone:</b> {$order.params.SHIPINFO.Consignee.ToMobile} / {$order.params.SHIPINFO.Consignee.ToTelPhone} <br>
                        <b>Civil Id:</b><br>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                        <td><b>Pay Type: {$order.params.original_order_array.payment_method}</b></td>
                        <td>Amount: {$order.params.original_order_array.total} - Currency - {$order.params.original_order_array.codcurrency}  </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Reference 1</b></td><td>{$order.params.original_order_array.reference} </td></tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Reference 2</b></td><td></td></tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Service</b></td><td>{$order.other_data.service}</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">

                            <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>Pieces:</b></td> <td>1</td> <td><b>Weight:</b></td> <td>{$order.other_data.total_weight} Kg</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Remarks</b></td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <b>Note 2</b></td><td>{$order.other_data.original_order_data.notes2}</td></tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Shipper Order Number:</b></td>
                        <td>                            
                        <p style="font-family:IDAutomationHC39M;text-align: left">*{$order.other_data.awb}*</p>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>Shipment Date:</b></td><td>{$order.other_data.awb_date}</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>

{/foreach}

<script>
window.print();
</script>
```

screen shots 
[html view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2R7d.jpg)

[print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEr7R.jpg)

Thanks in advance.
Roshan

Comment: Have you tried it in multiple browsers? Have you tried it with background graphics turned on?

Comment: Can you show some more code? What you have here is not nearly enough. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @BrianAnderson: Hi, yes I tried with in FF and Chrome both are same. I see bar codes on HTML page but when printed no barcodes.

Comment: @MrLister: I updated my question with codes. Please note its a Smarty template. If I save this page in a separate html then I see the bar codes in print preview. It seems inside Prestashop something is preventing it to appear the barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Roshan save the below code in html format and check whether it shows barcode in your print preview . if it works than you should try changing your font or check your code again..it will be very helpful if you upload your code  here as well.also check display background graphics checkbox in print preview menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fontlibrary.org/face/idautomationhc39m-code-39-barcode' 
rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
p.serif {
    font-family: 'IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode', Times, serif;
}

p.sansserif {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="serif">This is a paragraph, shown in the Times New Roman font.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>123456790</p>
<p>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
<p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhi, unfortunately still the same result. It seems something to do with Prestashop styling..

Comment: welcome..but it is not the problem with prestashop but problem may be on your system.. try on another computer n that will work for sure..

Comment: Hi Abhi, thanks for your reply. I do not agree with this. If my system has an issue then the barcarole should should not be appearing at all. Anyhow I switched my html to a PDF using TCPDF and now problem is solved. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Look for the link to the font itself in the header. It should look like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/idautomationhc39m-code-39-barcode" type="text/css"/>
```

Change the `media="screen"` to `media="screen, print"`.

I would also recommend you try using `'IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode'` instead of `IDAutomationHC39M` for font family. (Make sure the quotes are there.)

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that did not work either.. So as to save time I switched this HTML page as a PDF and used TCPDF. This solved my problem. Thanks again.